# Is it safe to bind an unsigned int to a signed int reference?

Tags: c++, reference

After coming across something similar in a co-worker's code, I'm having trouble understanding why/how this code executes without compiler warnings or errors.

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int u = 42;

    const int& s = u;

    std::cout << "u=" << u << " s=" << s << "\n";

    u = 6 * 9;

    std::cout << "u=" << u << " s=" << s << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
u=42 s=42
u=54 s=42
```

First, I expect the compiler to issue some kind of diagnostic when I mix signed/unsigned integers like this. Certainly it does if I attempt to compare with `<`. That's one thing that confuses me.

Second, I'm not sure how the second line of output is generated. I expected the value of `s` to be 54. How does this work? Is the compiler creating an anonymous, automatic signed integer variable, assigning the value of `u`, and pointing the reference `s` at that value? Or is it doing something else, like changing `s` from a reference to a plain integer variable?

Comment: `const int& s = u;` first creates a new temporary `int` which is then assigned to the `const int&`. That's why it won't work with a non-const reference

Comment: This is an interesting C++ gotcha that I've never seen before.

Comment: It may help understand the behavior to realize that in C++ a `const` reference can, in some cases, extend the lifetime of a temporary that is assigned to it. Basically, if the temporary was created during the initialization of the reference, in most cases it will extend the lifetime of the temporary to that of the reference. A function local variable is one of those cases.

Comment: See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) for more about the lifetime extension. "The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference [or to an rvalue reference (since C++11)], see reference initialization for details."

Comment: To answer your question:  **yes**, it is safe.  However, if what you *intended* is `const int& s = u;` to be *as if* `const int& s = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&u);` ... I don't think that is safe (in the sense that I think it is **undefined behavior**, but IANALL so I may be mistaken).

Comment: @Eljay UB by virtual of strict pointer aliasing.

Comment: @Eljay: this special case is not UB: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.2

Comment: @geza • Thank you for the correction, and finding chapter & verse!  I'll refrain from deleting my incorrect comment above, because it will break the comment thread continuity.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

References can't bind to objects with different type directly. Given `const int& s = u;`, `u` is implicitly converted to `int` firstly, which is a temporary, a brand-new object and then `s` binds to the temporary `int`. (Lvalue-references to `const` (and rvalue-references) could bind to temporaries.) The lifetime of the temporary is prolonged to the lifetime of `s`, i.e. it'll be destroyed when get out of `main`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This is completely counterintuitive to me.  No wonder why people dread C++!

Comment: Interesting stuff, this means that `printf("%p %p", &u, &s);` will print different values, as the two variables are stored on different locations in the stack.

Comment: @russoue If you follow C++ rules then you'll find it becomes intuitive. I'm quite addicted to these C++ things. :)